# issue in finding element after switchTo() in Selenium IE Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Hi I'm facing issue in trying to find element in the new window after performing a `switchTo(new Handle)` in IE Webdriver

The code that i'm using is

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

//some code

String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();  //store the current window handle

driver.findElement(By.name("element1")).click();  //opens a new window

//code to find the new window handle

driver.switchTo().window(NewWindowHandle);   //switch to new window 

String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();    //returns me the URL of the newly opened window

driver.findElement(By.name("element2")).click();  //click on element in new window
```

After the switch of the window, the `findElement()` is unable to find the new element, whereas the url of the new window is displayed correctly. 
I also performed a `driver.getTitle();` and that also was giving me the correct page title of the newly opened window.

I cross verified the element property and that was correct.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Is the element in the new window present inside any frame?

Comment: Did you try wait call? Might be that element is taking time to load.

Comment: @HemChe : No the element is not inside a frame.

Comment: @grm : yes the wait until browser loads is called.

Comment: @preeth Have you tried using different locators like css or xpath for locating the element?

Comment: @HemChe The same code works fine when i'm changing to firefox driver. The elements gets detected.

Answer (score -1):

Try this it worked for me:

```
 for(String NewWindowHandle:driver.getWindowHandles())
 {
    driver.switchTo().window(NewWindowHandle);   //switch to new window 
 }
```

Comment: I don't think this helps the OP; they don't have a problem with the switchTo() call, it's trying to locate elements after the switchTo() which is going wrong.

Comment: The switch is working fine. Its in the search for element in the new window the issue is